# getFullYear doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, datepicker

Im in the land of JavaScript and I'm trying some functions for my university project, but I got stuck in this part:

```
function validateDate(){
    alert("validateDate");
    var date = document.getElementById("dateN");
    var yearN = data.getFullYear();
    alert(yearN.value);
    var dateA = new Date();
    var yearA = dateA.getFullYear`enter code here`();
    alert(yearA.value);

    if(((yearA - yearN)<18) || ((yearA - yearN)>120)){
        alert("age between 18 and 120 only.");
        data.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

When I try to print the values, nothing happens, Which terrible wrong thing Im doing here guys?
The dateN is comes from another part (which is working =D ).

Sorry if its a very "noob" question,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `data.getFullYear();` what is `data` ?

Comment: What is `dateA.getFullYear\`enter code here\`();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two mistake here :

```js
var date = document.getElementById("dateN");
var yearN = data.getFullYear();
```

date is refering a DOM element an it is not a date !
data is undefined !

maybe you want make a Date with the value from "dateN" ?
so according to the HTMLElement you have to get his value and create a new Date !

```
 // saying is a input text and a valid date format !
 var date = new Date( document.getElementById("dateN").value );
```

---

```
 var yearA = dateA.getFullYear`enter code here`();
 //                                    ^
 // this is not valid o----------------|
```

Comment: Parsing of strings using the Date constructor is not recommended as it's largely implementation dependent.

Comment: @RobG yes sure, i agree. It is just to show OP that he need to get value before everything not about parsing date.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `data.getFullYear()` -

```
var yearN = data.getFullYear();
```

Don't you mean `date.getFullYear?`?